# Javascript error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, silverlight, internet-explorer

I have a problem with a js script running in Internet Explorer.

Basically the script runs fine in Firefox, but I need to embed it into the webbrowser control in a silverlight application, for which it has to run error free in the Internet Explorer engine.

Running it in the IE produces an "Expected object" error in the following line:

> $f("player", "player.swf", {

How could this be rewritten to also work in IE?

Here is the complete script:

> ```
>       $f("player", "player.swf", {
>                 key: '#@18a1aaa6552d45a2cfe',
>                 log: { level: 'debug', filter: 'org.flowplayer.cluster.*' },
>             clip: {
>             url: 'live3',
>             live: true,
>             provider: 'rtmp',
>             autoBuffer:true,
>             bufferLength:10,
>             scale:'fit',
>             connectionProvider: 'cluster',
>             onStart: function(clip){ }
>         },
>         canvas: {backgroundImage: 'url(staytuned.jpg)'},
>         onError:function(err){canvas: {backgroundImage: 'url(taytuned.jpg)'}},
>         contextMenu: [  
>                 'player 1.1',
>                 {'About  ...' : function() {
>                             location.href = "url/?page=aboutus";}},
>                 {'Contact ...' : function() {
>                             location.href = "url/?page=contactus";}},
>                 {'More Casts ...' : function() {
>                             location.href = "url/?page=casts";}},
>                         ],
>         plugins: {
> ```

```
            overlay:  {
                url: 'overlay.swf',
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    width: 854,
                    height:450,
                    zIndex:3
                },
                rtmp: {
                url: 'rtmp.swf'
                },  
            cluster: {
                url: 'cluster.swf',
                netConnectionUrl: 'url',
                hosts: [
                    {host:'url'},
                    {host:'url'}
                    ]
                },
            controls: {
                autoHide: false, 
                url:'url',
                zIndex:5
                },

    gatracker: {
        url: "analytics.swf",
        trackingMode: "Bridge",
        bridgeObject: "pageTracker"
    }
}
```

});

Thanks,
Andrej

Comment: please specify the version(s) of IE that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

First answer was incorrect. See comments for details.

**Edit**

The problem is likely that $f is not defined at the time you're trying to call it. Place `alert(typeof $f);` on the line immediately before the line causing the error. If it doesn't alert `function`, them I'm right.

Make sure you're including the script that contains the definition for $f before you try to call it.

Comment: With that additional brace even Firefox doesn't run the script anymore. The original brace counts looks fine as it is (at least in that part of the script), the one in the first line is closed at the end of the script, while with those changes it its closed immediatly after onStart.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I didn't see that final closing brace. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Goto www.jslint.com.  Paste this entire script into the top window and click the "jslint" button below it.

You'll find that onError is malformed:

```
onError:function(err){canvas: {backgroundImage: 'url(taytuned.jpg)'}},
```

it should read more like:

```
onError:function(err) {
   var canvas = {backgroundImage: 'url(taytuned.jpg)'};
   return canvas;
},
```

There's a similar issue a few lines below.

And I suspect that "taytuned.jpg" needs to be enclosed within quotes, but it's not my script.